# Can we use "before" instead of "until" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

"To experience enlightenment you must surrender and dissolve totally and completely into the Infinite Sea of Consciousness until there is nothing left of you"

In the sentence above, why can't we use 'before' instead of 'until'? Or are both correct?

Can anyone explain this pls?
Thankyou

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary and compared the meanings of 'before' and 'until'?

Comment: _In the sentence above, why can't we use 'before' instead of 'until'? Or are both correct?_

Answer (score 1):

No, these words are not interchangeable.

We would say "do [x] *before* [y]" either to mean that one action should be carried out before the other (eg brush your teeth before going to bed) or to impose a deadline of something that would inevitably happen anyway (eg go to bed before 10pm).

In your example, "there is nothing left of you" is neither an action nor an event that will happen anyway - it is a *result* of the action. Saying "do [x] *until* [y]" means that you continue the action and only cease when the result occurs.